# Display Dynamically created Array TypeScript , Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a dynamically generated array and I want that to get display on my HTML but, I am missing something which I m not able to figure it out 
   **app-component.ts**

```
StateClick(stateClicked,index) {

// StateName is an array from which I will get the index of my state.
var indexCollector = this.StateName.indexOf(stateClicked);

// Creating Array Dynamically
window['asd'+index] = new Array();

// CityName array from which i will get an array present at that index
this.asd0 = this.CityName[indexCollector];

// Value is visible in console
console.log(this.asd0);
}
```

**my array : Just Random Data**

```
StateName: any[] = ['Andhra Pradesh', 'Jharkhand', 'Kerala'];
CityName: any[] = [

[     'Adoni',
      'Amaravati',
      'Anantapur',
      'Tadepalligudem',
      'Tadipatri',
      'Tenali',
      'Tirupati',
      'Kadapa',
      'Kakinada',
      'Kurnool'
    ],
    ['Patna',
      'Gaya',
      'Muzaffarpur',
      'Darbhanga',
      'Bhagalpur',
      'Nalanda',
      'Tirupati',
      'Begusarai'
    ],
    ['Jamnagar',
      'Ankleshwar',
      'morbi',
      'Valsad',
      'Bhavnagar'
    ],
];
```

**app-component.html**

```
  <div *ngFor="let userCheckedValueDetails of userCheckedValue ; let idx = index">
 <select>
 <option [selected]=true>Select City</option>

 // This is where I trying to display my dynamically generated array but not able
   // to fetch it asd+idx

    <option value="{{StoringCityArray}}" *ngFor="let StoringCityArray of asd+idx">
        {{StoringCityArray}}
    </option>
 </select>
 </div>
```

As is shown in my code i am trying to fetch that array which is dynamically generated but i am not able to di it

Comment: Not clear enough, what do you mean for exemple by `asd+idx` try to [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com) it.

Comment: asd is myname and idx is index which is created so evry time will get new array with asd0,asd1,asd2,asd3,asd4 like this

Comment: asd+idx is a way I m trying to display my array

Answer (score 0):

You're array is not one dimensional, so you will either need to flatten your array and run *ngFor or run 2 nested *ngFor (Not recommended)

```
<option selected="true">Select City</option>
<option value="{{StoringCityArray}}" *ngFor="let StoringCityArray of asd_idx[0]">
    {{StoringCityArray}}
</option>
```

- You forgot to add doblequated on your first select, And since it's static there's no need in []
- I wouldn't recommend using the + sign as variable name..
- Init the Array like this (dont use window)

  states: any[] = [];
- Push new states to the array like this:

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
      states.push('Alaska');
  }

Comment: just check my code once again ,just forgoted to update a small part

Comment: I am creating an array with a different name,that's the reason I m using window